# Python imports aren't installing / can't be found

Tags: python, pip, python-import, importerror

Firstly, I'm super new to Python/code and stackoverflow, so apologies if I sound like a child trying to explain complex rocket science.

I'm following a tutorial on creating a fake teachers database, and they say

```py
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
import panda
```

however, when I go to import, I get an error of

```
ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:
pytz: No module named 'pytz'
dateutil: No module named 'dateutil'
```

Despite the modules being imported and in the Python folder. It took me around 30 minutes to get MySQL imported, and honestly I'm not even really sure how it fixed. I renamed the folder, I copied the folder into the virtual environment I'm using (which I'm not even sure how to *not* use that, it seems to just create difficulties in doing any importing), I had to reinstall pip multiple times as it also error'd the first 2 tries. I'm really confused and a little frustrated as I have zero idea how to fix this, or what even the errors are in the first place.

Any help would be much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Pip should be included with your Python installation. Try `pip install mysql` and `pip install panda`. If that doesn't work try `py -m pip install mysql` and `py -m pip install panda`.

Comment: I had already attempted that before, tried again just incase and the cmd says it's sucessfully installed, but still get the 'no module named: x' error when I run it through PyCharm.

Comment: Are you sure PyCharm has the version of python you are using? Just in case, do `python -version`. The version of python on pycharm should be there at the bottom right. If this still doesn't work try using a different editor like VSCode or IDLE.

Comment: Where do I type that? PyCharm doesn't seem to recognize that (neither does the python console)

Answer (score 0):

Try: 
`pip3 install mysql pytz`

You can install multiple packages at the same time!

Comment: Tried this, got a long box of red, not sure exactly what it was saying, but if I do them individually then it installs! Still not working in the import section though :/

Comment: What kind of environment are you using? Are you using a virtual environment? If you can reproduce the error and tell us the last traceback that would help.

Comment: Using a virtual environment in PyCharm, I was watching a python tutorial on YT and just followed their directions, which did include the PATH box checked. I created a new environment from File>NewProject, didn't change anything just kept defaults, and then tried this code again and it still error'd out. Here's what it gave me, the same as the other time:
`C:/Users/epsil/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/ImportTest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\pythonProject\ImportTest.py", line 1, in <module>
    import mysql.connector
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql' `

Comment: @JupiterVomit When you go to the configuration settings of the pycharm environment (top right next to play button, then click on edit configurations), what do you see under python interpreter? You could have selected a different interpreter. Try changing it to a different interpreter

Comment: Okay, it was set to a different interpreter folder than where the project was, changed it to the same one as I'm using and also a different one I had, and still same error, 'no module named 'mysql' '

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get out of the virtual environment you created you can use the `deactivate` command.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

See If pip is installed in your system
If its Installed , Install pytz by exeuting

```
pip install pytz
```

Install Pip = https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
Just download and run this file